# Logging to Papertrail with PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2, papertrail-app

I'm trying to get my node app logs to show up on papertrail using pm2 as my process manager.

As of now, I have the pm2 logging to a file defined in my `process.json`. I want to set it up where I keep a local copy of my logs as well as send them to papertrail so I can see them without ssh.

I followed the papertrail start guide and added the output to `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and on papertrail's console, i see the following:

```
Sep 28 16:35:47 ip-172-31-16-83 sudo:    ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu/api-nodejs ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/rsyslog.conf
Sep 28 16:35:47 ip-172-31-16-83 sudo:  pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
Sep 28 16:36:03 ip-172-31-16-83 sudo:  pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 28 16:36:05 ip-172-31-16-83 sudo:    ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu/api-nodejs ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/rsyslog.conf
Sep 28 16:36:05 ip-172-31-16-83 sudo:  pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
Sep 28 16:36:23 ip-172-31-16-83 sudo:  pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 28 16:36:27 ip-172-31-16-83 sudo:    ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu/api-nodejs ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service rsyslog restart
Sep 28 16:36:27 ip-172-31-16-83 sudo:  pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
Sep 28 16:36:27 ip-172-31-16-83 rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="12850" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Sep 28 16:36:27 ip-172-31-16-83 rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="12939" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Sep 28 16:36:27 ip-172-31-16-83 rsyslogd-2307:  warning: ~ action is deprecated, consider using the 'stop' statement instead [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2307 ]
Sep 28 16:36:27 ip-172-31-16-83 rsyslogd:  rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104
Sep 28 16:36:27 ip-172-31-16-83 rsyslogd:  rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Sep 28 16:36:27 ip-172-31-16-83 sudo:  pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Anyone got some experience with pm2 and paprtrail? Is PM2 completely bypassing rsyslog and is there a way for me to pipe pm2's log to papertrail another way?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to make a [pm2 module](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/advanced/pm2-module-system/#creating-a-module) that listen for logs event (which is `log:out` or `log:err`) with [pm2 bus api](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/) and send them where you want them to go.